# Databricks Spark-Redshift: Hanging when mode is 'overwrite', writing df out to Redshift

Tags: apache-spark, locking, amazon-redshift

using this as the initial command ...

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/miniconda/bin/python nohup spark-submit --deploy-mode client --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:3.0.0-preview1 --jars RedshiftJDBC4-1.2.1.1001.jar  s3_to_redshift_ingest.py    -t  tbl_tbl_name   -ic 201809 > tbl_tbl_name_dev.txt 2>&1
```

I can see that the df is written out successfully to the S3 temp dir, but my script hangs when trying to Copy from S3 to Redshift.  Here is my code:

```
    w_mode = 'overwrite'

try:
    df.write\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
    .option("url","jdbc:redshift:<removed for posting>)\
    .option("dbtable", rs_target)\
    .option("tempdir", "<removed for posting>")\
    .option("aws_iam_role","<removed for posting>")\
    .option("extracopyoptions","TRIMBLANKS")\
    .option("extracopyoptions","MAXERROR 1000")\
    .option("extracopyoptions","TRUNCATECOLUMNS")\
    .option("tempformat","CSV GZIP")\
    .mode(w_mode)\
    .save()
```

While troubleshooting, I  am seeing dual locks in the Redshift instance.  IT seems that these dual locks are the issue, but I don't know how to keep those from happening.

[image: Redshift locks]

So, has anyone seen or better yet solved this same issue?

Comment: are you sure you dont have 2 of these running at the same time?

Comment: Confident.  spun up a new cluster, ran script w same hang result

Comment: @ThomRogers - Wanted to check if were you able to solve this, I m also experiencing a similar issue while writing the contents of a `DataFrame`